# Force browser to reload "cached server side html file data through javascript"

Tags: javascript, caching, query-string, cache-control

I have an `login.dxview` file

```
    <div id="divLoginNews">
        <div data-bind="html:newsContent" style="color:white;"></div>
    </div>
```

Above div block shows news.html file content.
news.html file is at server side.
below javascript code reads `news.html`

```
$.ajax({
    url: oClientInfo.sRootAddress + '/Information/news.html',
    error: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        viewModel.newsContent(data);
    }
});
```

issue is if I update the `news.html` content on page reload, the content is not updated in browser.
I understand that in above url, if I get the file modified date as url query string, it should solve issue. I want to syntax for the same. I could not find it till now.
(I want to re-load file from server, only when it was changed.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add parameter like current time on the URL to avoid caching

```
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + today.getMinutes() + today.getSeconds();

$.ajax({
    url: oClientInfo.sRootAddress + '/Information/news.html?time=' + time,
    error: function () {
    },
    success: function (data) {
        viewModel.newsContent(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: This code will load file everytime as time will be different everytime. If we can get file modified datetime, that is best I think. But how can we do that, if you know syntax please share.